# How to extract the max and min date from listbox on userform1?

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

I have a listbox on `UserForm1` with data.
I want to extract the smallest date and largest date from the first column in the listbox and put them in `textbox1` and `textbox2`.

I expect
`textbox1 = min date in first column in listbox1`
`textbox2 = max date in first column in listbox1`

Comment: ty i found the solve

Answer (score 0):

```
With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) = False Then
            If CLng(.List(i, 0)) > lngMyMaxValue Then
                lngMyMaxValue = CLng(.List(i, 0))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
 Textbox2 = lngMyMaxValue
```

Comment: Textbox1= Me.ListBox2.List(i, 0)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?